# jQuery UI droppable float back

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am building an app utilizing jQuery UI draggable/droppable.

I need to drag boxes from the left into target boxes on the right. It works fine, however if a value box id dropped not on any target boxes it needs to float back into the left-side section.

It sort of works if I drag it a little and then release but when it is further away it just sits there. I've added

```
$(".card").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
```

but it does not seem to help. What am I missing?

Here's [DEMO](http://www.c8r.us/ux4vQr).

Comment: What's your `droppable` initialization look like?  What's your `tolerance` setting for the `droppable` container?

Comment: Just added DEMO -- it's easier to show than explain.

Comment: @David Hoerster tolerance: "intersect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think based on your demo that your draggable is not reverting because it's actually hitting a valid droppable target (the #dropZone element in your demo, which is essentially the background).

You can fix it by not turning that element into a droppable or by making it's drop handler "revert" the draggable element itself.